# Tomcat: *-Mapping breaks websocket endpoint

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I've a Tomcat 7.0.54 with a CometServlet:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.test.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MyServlet.java

```
class MyServlet extends HttpServlet implements CometProcessor ...
```

TestEndpoint.java

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket1")
public class TestEndpoint { ...
```

With this configuration, I'm unable to connect to the websocket endpoint. When I change the url pattern to for example /a/*, everything works as expected.

Do you know of any workaround for this? I really have to use the /* url pattern because a I use one servlet that dispatches all requests and there must no be anything else in the url.

Thanks in advance.
Peter